# ASP.NET button handles method not working in IE11

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cross-browser

I am using ASP.NET 2.0 Web Forms. I have an asp.button which looks like this:

```
asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="Save"
```

I have a handles method in the code behind, the header looks like this:

```
 Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
```

For some reason the handles method is never reached in IE10 or IE11. It works fine in Chrome and IE9. Does anyone have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

This a problem in the browser definition files for Internet Explorer depending on the installed version of the Microsoft .NET Framework. You can find a hotfix from Microsoft in the following link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Comment: That uses .NET 4, is there something similar for .NET 2?